# Use custom table or wp_post table for custom post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have an website with huge data in its database now I want to rebuild it in wordpress. So in this order I have to create custom post type and custom data fields in wordpress. Since wordpress saves all data in 'wp_post' and 'wp_postmeta' tables then how can I import my all data from existing database into wordpress database.

Should I use custom table in wordpress, if yes then how can I do that.?

please suggest me a better way.

Comment: Could you explain what Huge data is. 1 TB, 100 TB, something else? Also - how many rows in the database? It's best to research an article and explain why it's not helping you. This risks being closed as too broad without some self-help documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a plugin for WordPress to handle your specific data type. Wordpress supports [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types). According to the linked WordPress page, it does not seem to mention additional tables. There is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) that supposedly offer the same functionality (did not test it).

Comment: Thanks @Hamdi for your reply..Yes.I am creating my own plugin and I am creating custom post type in it. So should I use wordpress tables or my own custom tables. Since data in database is in very large amount.